# Alteryx Upgrade - No workflow data in Gallery

Tags: mongodb, alteryx

We are working on upgrading our Alteryx application as well as the MongoDB version.

We have created a non-production environment to test the upgrade. Since the non-production environment is new, and Alteryx and MongoDB have just been installed to it, it has no existing data yet.

We tried to migrate our prod MongoDB data into the non-prod MongoDB so we could perform testing.

The scheduled workflows are being triggered, however, we don’t see the workflows on the Alteryx Gallery. We’re expecting that the non-prod would be a replica of the prod with the data being imported to it.